# Vista Won't Show System Information

Tags: windows-vista

If I go to the System Information screen (Control Panel -> System), Processor/Ram appears as Not Available.  There is nothing printed next to the Rating option.

Any idea what would cause this and how to get it to refresh?

Answer (score 5):

[From TechArena](http://forums.techarena.in/vista-hardware-devices/811189.htm):

> 1. Click Start, type `%SYSTEMROOT%\Performance\WinSat\DataStore` in the "Start Search" box, and
>      then press ENTER:
> 2. Delete all the .xml files in the folder.
> 3. Click Start, type performance information and tools in the Start
>      Search box, and then click Performance
>      Information and Tools in the Programs
>      list.
> 4. If the following information appears, click Refresh Now to update
>      the Windows Experience Index:
>
>    "Your Windows Experience Index needs to be refreshed.
>
>    If you are prompted for an administrator password or confirmation, type the password or click Continue.
>
>    Windows Experience Index assesses the
>      components in the computer.
> 5. Note the value that appears next to Your computer has a Windows Experience
>      Index base score of.
> 6. Click Update my score.

Comment: There was one xml file.  Removed, followed directions and it scored it on this screen.

Went back to System Information and the information was still Not Available.  Rebooted just in case, but it didn't make a difference.

Comment: Damn. The only other solution I've seen so far is to format/reinstall Windows.

Answer (score -5):

Go to a command prompt and try this:

> c:>net localgroup administrators
>   NetworkService /ADD

Comment: The NetworkService account should **NOT** be an administrator. The NetworkService account is meant for minimum privileges on the system while allowing access to the network as the computer account. By granting a low level system account administrative permissions can potentially open you to larger security holes because the services running as NetworkService will not be administrators. You can reference the MSDN article for the NetworkService account at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684272(VS.85).aspx.

Comment: Although this information appears on Microsoft Technet, the answer was not from a MSFT employee, and this is a bad bad bad idea for the reasons **@Joshua** stated above. http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/itprovistasetup/thread/b3414a97-3eca-4d18-a755-3c36635ccb71

Comment: Interesting, didn't know.  That is where I found this, but I didn't consider all the ramifications; thanks for the warning.

Comment: Tried this anyway from searching and it didn't make a difference.  Used /delete to go back.